# Parsing a brief string with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There is no way around confessing it. The only reason this question is here is an extreme laziness manifesting itself as an attempt to avoid reading the

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/')
html = response.read()
print len(html)
```

274574 bytes of documentation of BeautifulSoup, just to handle the rather simple href tag that you see in the following lines.

```
mystr = '<a href="gazette.html" detail="particularities">Access it!</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(mystr, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Naturally the prettification looks like

```
<a detail="particularities" href="gazette.html">
 Access it!
</a>
```

Now I'd like to answer the questions:

1. Is there indeed an `a` tag in `mystr`? and, after testing that there is:
2. Is there a detail tag? and, after testing that there is:
3. What is the value of the detail tag?
4. Finally, what is the content? ('Access it!' in this case)

Comment: Ctrl+f does wonders :) there's also a nice navigation menu on the left of the BeautifulSoup page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can answer your questions in order.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mystr = '<a href="gazette.html" detail="particularities">Access it!</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(mystr, 'html.parser')

a = soup.find('a')
if a: # a will be None if there are no <a> tags
    try:
        detail = a['detail']
        print "Detail: {}".format(detail)
        print "Content: {}".format(a.text)
    except KeyError: # will throw KeyError if no key named 'detail'
        print "No details"
        print "Content: {}".format(a.text)
else:
    print "No <a> tags"
```

Answer (score -1):

I read the docs:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mystr = '<a href="gazette.html" detail="particularities">Access it!</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(mystr, 'html.parser')
a = soup.findAll('a', detail='particularities')[0]
print a.text
```

- (only because I'm a nice guy)